# How can i write a program which reports on status of SQL Server replication

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-replication

Some of our end users are not IT savvy and may not know how to check the health of the SQL replication system. Are there any tools which are simpler than SQL Server Management Studio that they can keep an eye on ? I am asking this since the end users are non programmers.

If not, what are the ways for the admin in the client place, or the Central office to keep a tab on the health of the SQL replication tasks in remote client sites ?

Thanks and regards,
Chak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in Replication Monitor;

The default path is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlmonitor.exe

See the following; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151780.aspx